# Run chromium-browser on Linux with fullscreen and application modes ON

Tags: chromium, kiosk

Some time ago the Chromium-browser was supporting a so called "kiosk mode", which could start Chromium in fullscreen and removed unnecessary titlebar and some other UI components.

Right now it looks like it's no longer supported. After few updates the same script that I was using for launching kiosk mode is not behaving the same.

I checked some sites and learnt that recently they introduced a so called "**application mode**" (`--app=http://mysite.com`). All cool and neat, but application mode does no longer enforce fullscreen.

How could I **force chromium-browser** to behave exactly as in previous **kiosk mode**?